# How to get Good Quality Bitmap image after capture from camera in Android?

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera-intent, bitmapimage

I am trying to get Bitmap image after Capture image from camera. What i am doing first i save a image into memory and then getting a bitmap image from image path.

```
private String imageFilePath =null;
    private void openCameraIntent() {
                Intent pictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                if(pictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null){
                    File photoFile = null;
                    try {
                        photoFile = createImageFile();
                    } catch (IOException ex) {

                    }
                    if (photoFile != null) {
                         photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID +".fileprovider", photoFile);
                         pictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
                        startActivityForResult(pictureIntent, REQUEST_CAPTURE_IMAGE);
                    }
                }
            }

        private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
                String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss",
                                Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
                String imageFileName = "IMG_" + timeStamp + "_";
                File storg =
                        getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
                File image = File.createTempFile(
                        imageFileName,  /* prefix */
                        ".jpg",         /* suffix */
                        storg      /* directory */
                );

                imageFilePath = image.getAbsolutePath();
                return image;
            }

public Bitmap bitmapimage(String path) {
        return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
    }
```

But in my case i don't want to save image into memory. I want to get bitmap image after Capture image. I tried it but i am getting very low quality image. How can i get good quality bitmap image without saving into memory. please help me to do this. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

That's true. The camera intent can only pass a high resolution image as a file. You can delete it as soon as your app recovers control, even though it is usually done in `onActivityResult()` callback.

Note that by then, the picture have been indexed in device MediaStore, a.k a. Gallery.

The alternative is to use the camera API instead of intent. Some wrapper libraries, like fotoapparat, may help.